# Wildfly 11 - High Availability - Single deploy on slave

Tags: high-availability, jgroups, wildfly-11

I have two servers in a HA mode. I'd like to know if is it possible to deploy an application on the slave server? If yes, how to configure it in jgroups? I need to run a specific program that access the master database, but I would not like to run on master serve to avoid overhead on it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

JGroups itself does not know much about WildFly and the deployments, it only creates a communication channel between nodes. I don't know where you get the notion of master/slave, but JGroups always has single* node marked as coordinator. You can check the membership through [Channel.getView()](http://www.jgroups.org/javadoc/org/jgroups/Channel.html#getView--).

However, you still need to deploy the app on both nodes and just make it inactive if this is not its target node.

*) If there's no split-brain partition, or similar rare/temporal issues